# \newcommand Error Either Way

Tags: macros, errors, pdftex

I have two documents, both starting with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Macros}
\begin{document}
```

where `Macros` is my own style file.  There are no other packages or definitions in either of the documents.  I have been using this for months without issue.  Tonight, one of the documents, after compiling many times without any errors, started throwing

```
LaTeX Error: Command \G already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

where I have `\newcommand{\G}{\gamma}` in the file `Macros`.

This error normally means that I have tried to use `\newcommand` on a command that is already defined, which is very straightforward.  The problem tonight is that I can compile the other document without the error, even though it uses *exactly* the same list of user defined commands.  What could possibly cause this?

If I comment out the offending line of Macros.sty then the problem document gives the error

```
LaTeX Error: Command \G unavailable in encoding OT1.
```

while the normal document gives the expected

```
Undefined control sequence.
```

error.

EDIT:
After TeXWorks crashed and I reopened the files, both compiled without any errors, so I believe the problem was within TeXWorks.  I am accepting David's answer because it would be helpful if a similar problem appears again, and to show that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Could we have a pair of minimal (non)working examples?

Comment: I sent the full files to a friend in the meantime, and they both worked for him.  I unplugged my external monitor to get a better screenshot of the error message I had, and my LaTeX editor crashed. When I reloaded it everything works fine.  I will edit my question appropriately.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the error appears to be caused by hardware issue not related to TeX and friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is defining `\G` so you can insert

```
\show\G
```

at several points in your document or package and at each tex will stop and show the definition.

The error message indicates that `\G` has an encoding specific command definition. My local tex tree has the following possibilities

```
allrunes/ara.fd:\DeclareTextSymbol{\G}{LRA}{167}
fc/t4enc.def:\DeclareTextAccent{\G}{T4}{'237}% double grave accent
hyperref/puenc.def:\DeclareTextCommand{\G}{PU}[1]{#1\83\017}% U+030F
teubner/teubner.sty:\DeclareTextCommand{\G}{\GRencoding@name}[1]{\lift@accent{96}{#1}}
```

So you must be loading a definition similar to one of these.

Comment: The error stopped on its own (see comment above), so I can't check that anymore.  I will keep `\show` in mind though, thanks.